# Cómo generar un diccionario estadístico con variables predefinidas

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, estadística

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Desarrolle una función en Python que recibe un DataFrame y dos números de columna y que
retorna en un diccionario con el nombre de las variables correspondientes a las columnas (como
llave), la covarianza y la correlaci´on entre esas dos variables. Verifique la correctitud de esta función usando la tabla ejemplo estudiantes.csv.

De ahí generé este script:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('ejemplo_estudiantes.csv', delimiter = ';', decimal = ",", header=0, index_col = 0)
df.Ciencias.value_counts()
df.Matematicas.value_counts()

y = df['Espanol'] 
x = df['Matematicas']


def estadisticas (x,y):
  covarianza = np.cov(x,y)
  correlacion = np.corrcoef(x,y)
    return {'Variable_1'  : x,
        'Variable_2' : y,
        'Correlacion' : np.corrcoef(x,y),
        'Covarianza' :  np.cov(x,y)}
```

Cuando intenté llamar a la función "Estadisticas" me da error, me dice esto:

```
estadisticas(df,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-152-b31ee91b8c29>", line 1, in <module>
    estadisticas(df,0)

  File "<ipython-input-146-da7391ff141b>", line 3, in estadisticas
    covarianza = np.cov(x,y)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in cov

  File "/Users/heinerleivagmail.com/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2390, in cov
    X = np.concatenate((X, y), axis=0)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 5 and the array at index 1 has size 1
```

Esta es la tabla original de donde tomé mis datos:

```
     Matematicas  Ciencias  Espanol  Historia  EdFisica
Lucia           7.0       6.5      9.2       8.6       8.0
Pedro           7.5       9.4      7.3       7.0       7.0
Ines            7.6       9.2      8.0       8.0       7.5
Luis            5.0       6.5      6.5       7.0       9.0
Andres          6.0       6.0      7.8       8.9       7.3
Ana             7.8       9.6      7.7       8.0       6.5
Carlos          6.3       6.4      8.2       9.0       7.2
Jose            7.9       9.7      7.5       8.0       6.0
Sonia           6.0       6.0      6.5       5.5       8.7
Maria           6.8       7.2      8.7       9.0       7.0
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para retornar el diccionario que puse arriba (estadisticas) y que me muestre lo que hice?

Comment: No puedes llamarlo `estadisticas(df,0)`, pero si como `estadisticas(x, y)` o `estadisticas(df['Matematicas'], df['Espanol'])`.

Answer (score 1):

La función `estadisticas` hay que llamar con una x y una y que son listas con valores numéricos.

Un ejemplo seria:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columnas = ['nombre', 'Matematicas', 'Ciencias', 'Espanol', 'Historia', 'EdFisica']
lineas = [['Lucia ', 7.0, 6.5, 9.2, 8.6, 8.0],
          ['Pedro ', 7.5, 9.4, 7.3, 7.0, 7.0],
          ['Ines  ', 7.6, 9.2, 8.0, 8.0, 7.5],
          ['Luis  ', 5.0, 6.5, 6.5, 7.0, 9.0],
          ['Andres', 6.0, 6.0, 7.8, 8.9, 7.3],
          ['Ana   ', 7.8, 9.6, 7.7, 8.0, 6.5],
          ['Carlos', 6.3, 6.4, 8.2, 9.0, 7.2],
          ['Jose  ', 7.9, 9.7, 7.5, 8.0, 6.0],
          ['Sonia ', 6.0, 6.0, 6.5, 5.5, 8.7],
          ['Maria ', 6.8, 7.2, 8.7, 9.0, 7.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnas, data=lineas)
df.set_index('nombre', inplace=True)

y = df['Espanol']
x = df['Matematicas']

def estadisticas(x, y):
    return {'Variable_1': x,
            'Variable_2': y,
            'Correlacion': np.corrcoef(x, y),
            'Covarianza': np.cov(x, y)}

estadisticas(x, y)
```

Para trabajar con el dataframe, se puede escribir la función con un dataframe y los nombres de dos columnas. Y para comparar cada 2 columnas, [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) es un manera cómoda para coger cada combinación:

```py
import itertools

def estadisticas(df, col_x, col_y):
    return {'Variable_1': col_x,
            'Variable_2': col_y,
            'Correlacion': np.corrcoef(df[col_x], df[col_y]),
            'Covarianza': np.cov(df[col_x], df[col_y])}

for col_x, col_y in itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2):
    print(estadisticas(df, col_x, col_y ))
```

Lo más cómodo para visualizar es la función [`pairplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) de la librería `seaborn`:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# df = ....

g = sns.pairplot(df)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Obtendrías:

[image: pairplot]